# handling identical express routes

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am buiding an app with NodeJS/Express/Mongoose and I'm trying to put in a suspend user route, though I'm struggling with how the routes should be defined to avoid any duplication.

I currently have these routes for creating a new user profile and subsequently editing that profile, both of which reference the User model.

`router.get("/users/:id", isLoggedIn, asyncErrorHandler(getUserProfile));`

`router.put("/users/:id", isLoggedIn,(updateUserProfile));`

The profile owner is the only user who can edit/update their profile, and they must input a password to do so.  That all works fine.

However, I am now creating a separate 'suspend user' route, which would be updated by a separate admin/moderator.  The new route is working fine to bring up the form:

`router.get("/users/:id/suspend", isLoggedIn, asyncErrorHandler(getSuspendUser));`

But when it comes to the put route, it also references the same user model to update, so how do I avoid a duplication of the above put route (which from my understanding is not allowed)?

`router.put("/users/:id", isLoggedIn, asyncErrorHandler(putSuspendUser));`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you're doing should be fine. You can have routes with the same name for different `VERBS` if you want different behavior. Just as you could use `router.all()` for all of the different `VERBS` if you wanted identical behavior.

Comment: hi @silencedogood, thanks though I'm not finding that to be the case; when I submit the form for the suspend route, it is diverting to the updateUserProfile route as it also uses the path router.put("/users/:id".  A I missing something here?  Thanks

Comment: Well, the way you've defined your routes seems counter-intuitive unless I'm missing something. Why not use `("/users/suspend/:id")` rather than `("/users/:id/suspend")`??

Comment: I think this is probably a bit of a lack of understanding on my part in terms of the correct conventions to use; I was really basing on the routes I currently have set up.  I have gone with Victor's approach below but thanks for your input also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend separating the admin routes from the regular route. This should solve all problems:

```
router.get("/users/:id", isLoggedIn, asyncErrorHandler(getUserProfile));
router.put("/users/:id", isLoggedIn,(updateUserProfile));

router.get("/admin/users/:id/suspend", isLoggedIn, asyncErrorHandler(getSuspendUser));
router.put("/admin/users/:id", isLoggedIn, asyncErrorHandler(putSuspendUser));
```

Then you can add additional middleware that checks if the user is actually an admin on the admin routes :)

Doing a `GET` on `/admin/users/:id` is a no-operation, if you'd like you can just reuse the code to return the user as per `GET /users/:id` but practically speaking, you'd never use it.

Comment: Thanks Victor!  Yes I agree that makes sense and is working now, seems I had a secondary problem as well which is why I was struggling originally but the admin route is a good call (I already have the middleware).